# ResultHandler for multiple ref cursors

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm trying to use a custom result handler on a procedure that returns 2 refcursors. Same logic works fine when only using one cursor output, but when there are two, resultContext inside the resultHandler is null. Appreciate any help!

> Mapper

```
{call some_pkg.some_proc(
            #{some_param, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},
            #{output_a, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, mode=OUT, resultMap=output_a_map},
            #{output_b, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, mode=OUT, resultMap=output_b_map})}
```

> Querying DB passing result handler

```
sqlSession.select(queryName, criteria, customResultHandler);
```

> Inside result handler that works when only one output is present

```
@Override
public void handleResult(ResultContext resultContext) {
    //resultContext is empty here
}
```